# Select values by date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have same data structure as [Select only last value of date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679701/select-only-last-value-of-date)
, but i need to get values for each date, I marked them. The solution for Feroc's question is giving last date only.

```
localName Date_Time                 RH  
BAG012    2014-10-09 17:17:58.000   16  <--     
BAG012    2014-10-09 17:13:28.000   16  
BAG012    2014-10-09 17:12:23.000   16  
BAG012    2014-10-09 16:52:54.000   16  
BAG012    2014-10-08 05:14:56.000   16  <--         
BAG012    2014-10-08 04:45:31.000   16  
BAG012    2014-10-08 04:44:08.000   16  
SAG165    2014-10-28 11:22:14.000   698 <--         
SAG165    2014-10-28 11:09:14.000   698     
SAG165    2014-10-28 10:53:18.000   698     
SAG165    2014-10-27 19:30:14.000   693 <--         
SAG165    2014-10-27 19:14:51.000   693     
SAG165    2014-10-27 19:13:56.000   693
```

Here is a code I am using:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT LTRIM(localName) as localName, CAST(year(Date_Time) as varchar)+'-'+CAST(month(Date_Time) as varchar)+'-'+CAST(day(Date_Time) as varchar) as date_time, RH, tank, mode,
     RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY localName ORDER BY Date_Time DESC)
   FROM dbo.SMCData
)

SELECT DISTINCT Date_Time, localName, RH, tank, mode
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 
order by LocalName asc
```

1. as the datetime includes time also, I tried to remove time and leave only date.
2. Tried to used DISTINCT Date_Time

both above cases are not making any changes in result.

ANSWER:
thanks for all, the following worked for me:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT localName, Date_Time, RH,
     RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY localName, CAST(Date_Time AS date) ORDER BY Date_Time DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT localName, Date_Time, RH
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY localName, Date_Time;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT localName, Date_Time, RH,
     RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY localName, CAST(Date_Time AS date) ORDER BY Date_Time DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT localName, Date_Time, RH
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY localName, Date_Time;
```

Comment: It is giving one value for date, independent how many different localName i have

Answer (score 0):

Use select distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date
FROM table_name
```

It will give you on of each date

Comment: This is not what the OP want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT localName, Date , RH
FROM table_name
```

This should give unique date and RH values and corresponding localName.

Comment: This is not what the OP want however.

Comment: yes - I see OP's additional comments in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the date also:

```
SELECT localName, MAX(date_time) AS max_date_time, MAX(rh) AS max_rh
FROM your_table
GROUP BY localName, CAST(date_time AS date)
```

This will give you the last date for each localname.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb559/3)

Output:

```
localName  max_date_time           max_rh
---------- ----------------------- -----------
BAG012     2014-10-08 05:14:56.000 16
BAG012     2014-10-09 17:17:58.000 16
SAG165     2014-10-27 19:30:14.000 693
SAG165     2014-10-28 11:22:14.000 698
```

Comment: This is working but not exactly. It is repeating for dates where RH also changing value.
localName max_date_time RH
 BAG015 2014-09-15 23:59:32.000 190
 BAG015 2014-09-16 23:59:59.000 190
 BAG015 2014-09-17 11:36:59.000 190
 BAG015 2014-10-09 18:22:15.000 335
 BAG015 2014-10-09 19:23:55.000 336
 BAG015 2014-10-09 20:10:12.000 337
 BAG015 2014-10-09 21:04:22.000 338
 BAG015 2014-10-09 23:05:14.000 339
 BAG015 2014-10-10 09:25:50.000 339
 BAG015 2014-10-10 10:11:58.000 340
 BAG015 2014-10-10 11:10:14.000 341
 BAG015 2014-10-10 12:11:55.000 342
 BAG015 2014-10-10 18:16:25.000 343

Comment: What i need is - to get last value of localName for each date.
Your solution is giving several outputs of the same localName for one date if value of RH is different. I need only last value for date

Comment: I need RH value, but last value for the date. if there are more than 1 RH value (which are different) i need only last

Comment: I wanted to mark you answer as "useful", but I do not have enough reputaion for that.
Thanks for help

Comment: @ADO_kg It's ok. both answers work. Mine should perform better though.

Comment: You are right, your solution works much faster. less than one second, while the accepted answer more than 2 secs